# Porque mi div no se pega al fondo

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo este código:

```
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#menu"><img src="Img/icons8_menu_32px.png" alt="Image not found"></a>
    <div class="menu" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Especies</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sobre el Parque</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- Demas elementos -->
</body>
```

Sucede que el div con clase .menu tiene una posicion absoluta y un tamaño 50vw ancho y 100% de alto y no se pega al fondo solo se pega al tamaño del viewport height. Y debajo del header hay mas contenido por lo que si hago scroll pues se ve el contenido y necesito que llegue al final de la pagina sin importar la cantidad de contenido. Alguien podría ayudarme con esto

Comment: Quieres un menú fijo a la parte de arriba? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Donde está el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].

Comment: estaría con posición absoluta relativo a que elemento? que sería "el fondo" al q nose pega?  Si es absolute y el ancestro relative ocupa todo el viewport podes darle top left y bottom